# Resize imageViews in a grid layout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to create a Tria games in android.
I have created a grid layout with 3 rows and 3 columns.
Inside the cells there 9 square imageViews.
I want occupy all the space of the grid layout, and the images must have the same dimensions.
How can I do this?

There is the layout

```
<GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:rowCount="3">
```

and this is a sample of an imageView

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_width="48dip"
                android:layout_height="48dip"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/android" />
```

(48dip is for an experiment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving fixed width and hight give in term of Weight

```
 android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: In which code? imageView or GridLayout? I didn't understand your answer

Comment: Parent element and image view in both.

Comment: android:layout_weight is not defined in imageViews.