# ImageView shrinks when put into GridLayout in Android studio

Tags: android, image, view, grid

I'm doing a game tutorial for something like Tic-Tac-Toe. First thing in the tutorial is to create a GridLayout and an ImageView inside. But once I do it, ImageView resize to a very small dot and I can't fix it in any way:
[image: ImageView becomes very small in GridView]

I have tried to:

1. Manually resize the image (value of width and height changes, but the image still apears tiny)
2. Check *Adjust View Bounds* property
3. Put the ImageView in different *layout_columns* and *layout_rows*
4. Set android:layout_weight="1" from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877005/resize-imageviews-in-a-grid-layout)

I was looking through another posts with this issue, but the difference is I haven't started to write the app code yet. I mean, I'm not so sure if I should use the solution presented for example here:
[Fixing tiny images in GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311355/fixing-tiny-images-in-gridview)
Is there another way to fix image size without writing special code in the starting section of the app?

My Android Studio version is 3.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried a sample and this worked

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/white_tick_green_bg" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/white_tick_green_bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/white_tick_green_bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/white_tick_green_bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/white_tick_green_bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/white_tick_green_bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/white_tick_green_bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/white_tick_green_bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/white_tick_green_bg" />
</GridLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Still doesn't work. I literally pasted your code, changed source and the layout broke: https://imgur.com/hfVMO9f
Tried to use android:adjustViewBounds="true" with no results

Comment: can you share the drawable image. It'll help to debug

Comment: height at line 35 is given as 183dp. Please replace it with "wrap_content"

Comment: also remove the adjustViewbouds=false. Better copy the code I posted and send me a screen shot